# Find the absolute path of an imported module

Tags: python, python-module

How can I get the absolute path of an imported module?

Comment: Do you mean the file system path to the file, or the Python module path?

Comment: In case anyone is looking to do this with a function `function_name.__code__` works nicely at getting the full file path.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

As the other answers have said, you can use `__file__`. However, note that this won't give the full path if the other module is in the same directory as the program. So to be safe, do something like this:

```
>>> import os
>>> import math
>>> os.path.abspath(math.__file__)
'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/math.so'
```

Here's an example with a module I made called `checkIP` to illustrate why you need to get the abspath (`checkIP.py` is in the current directory):

```
>>> import os
>>> import checkIP
>>> os.path.abspath(checkIP.__file__)
'/Users/Matthew/Programs/checkIP.py'
>>> checkIP.__file__
'checkIP.py'
```

Answer (score 9):

If it is a module within your PYTHONPATH directory tree (and reachable by placing a `__init__.py` in its directory and parent directories), then call its **path** attribute.

```
>>>import sample_module
>>>sample_module.__path__
['/absolute/path/to/sample/module']
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try:

```
import os
print os.__file__
```

to see where the module is located.